# User input required to update the date in my SQL file using Python

Tags: python, sql, string, date, replace

UPDATE! I am still looking for some way that to indicate to the user to make an update to these dates but I went with this method:

I declared a variable in my SQL file so it looks like:

```
    declare @date date = DATE
    Select * from table WHERE date = @date

and then in my python it looks like:

    DATE = date(2022, 10, 31)
    def sql_data(sql_path, date):
     with open(sql_path) as sql_file:
      sql = sql_file.read()
    
    sql = sql.replace("DATE", "'{}'".format(date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')))
      
    df = sql_data('sql_path', DATE)
     df.to_csv('csv path', index=False)
```

I have a Python script that will execute my SQL script and create a csv file. I need to run this csv file on a monthly basis -- I am trying to do two things:

1. Before my Python code executes and runs the SQL to create a csv file, I need to replace the date in my SQL statement first and update it to whatever month I will run this report.
2. Force the user who is running the Python to enter in a date that will replace the date in my SQL statement. I want a fail-safe that will not let the user move on with the code until the date is updated.

The SQL statement looks like:
select * from table as x
where x.date = '10/30/2022'

I need to replace the string 'MM/DD/YYY' to whatever date I want in the format of 'MM/DD/YYYY'. One issue is that the x.date value won't be the same since this SQL statement will be run on a monthly basis. I need the value of x.date to be based off what the user inputs.

So far I have this (ignore that I didn't establish a connection -- I just took it out of this description)

```
new_date = input("Enter in the reporting date here (format: 'MM/DD/YYYY')")

with open('myreport.sql', 'r') as sqlfile:
   str.replace(' .date = "XXXXX", 'new_date')
```

I'm unsure how to replace the string within my sql file since the date value is not necessarily consistent every time i run this report.

The SQL statement looks like:
select * from table as x
where x.date = **'10/31/2022'** (date isn't necessarily 10/31/2022)

Comment: Are you replacing the string inside the SQL file? You should post your current code and if you want to replace a string in the SQL file you should also post the string to be replaced.  We can't guess what your data and source looks like.

Comment: I'm essentially trying to replace the '10/31/2022' in this part "select * from table as x where x.date = '10/31/2022'". My issue is that the date value won't always be 10/31/2022...Is there a way to not hardcode the value -- in my string replace method?

Answer (score 0):

You still have not posted any code requested, but I still give it a try.

What you want is a parameterised query

```
cursor.execute("select * from table as x where x.date = (?)", (user_input))
```

This way you can define user_input and use it as part of the query.

You could also simply format a string:

```
query = f"select * from table as x where x.date = {user_input}"
```

But this is problematic as the user could inject unwanted code into your query.